# Custom post type with double taxonomy "filtering"

Tags: php, custom-post-type, taxonomy, wordpress

I'm desperate.

I want to have an archive page with my custom post type called "ff_awards". There are two custom taxonomy called: game, seeson.

- post type: **ff_awards**
- taxonomy 1: **fh_game** /GAME
- taxonomy 2: **fh_seeson** /SEESON

Here is the model which I try to achieve:

- **Game 1**

  - **Seeson 1**

    - all post in Game 1 and Seeson 1
  - **Seeson 2**

    - all post in Game 1 and Seeson 2
- **Game 2**

  - **Seeson 1**

    - all post in Game 1 and Seeson 1
  - **Seeson 2**

    - all post in Game 2 and Seeson 2

I try almost everything. Below is my actual code, which working only for model:

- **Game 1**

  - all post in Game 1

Also working this model:

- **Seeson 1**

  - all post in Seeson 1

    ```
     <?php
      //for a given post type, return all
      $post_type = 'ff_awards';
      $tax = 'aw_game';
      $tax_terms = get_terms($tax);
      if ($tax_terms) {
         foreach ($tax_terms  as $tax_term) {
            $args=array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1
         );

      $my_query = null;
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
         while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>


         <div> hero goes post</div>

     <?php
           endwhile;
          }
        wp_reset_query();
       }
      }
     ?>
    ```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Nope, this code is working, I mentioned it above, but just for 1 taxonomy. The code is only for illustration what I am done yet. But I need to add some more code, to works with two taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need the right syntax for your $args. Take a look at this: http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/

What you're after is around line 32: this example lets you filter by 2 taxonomy terms.

Comment: And If a want to get posts for all terms in taxonomy 1 or taxonomy 2 ? Not even specific terms like 'terms' => array( 'red', 'blue' ).